# CKEditor under Alfresco Share (4.2.a)

Tags: ckeditor, alfresco-share

I'm trying to get CKEditor running under Share ( http://code.google.com/p/share-extras/wiki/CKEditorFormControl ), in previous version (4.0.d) it worked correctly, but in newest build I have problems with it.
While accessing edit form it doesn't display anything on place of content, in log I have following:

```
9.7.2012 14:56:59 org.apache.jsp.error500_jsp _jspService
SEVERE: javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'site/my_sample_site/skins/kama/editor.css' in servlet with name 'Spring Surf Dispatcher Servlet'
9.7.2012 14:56:59 org.apache.jsp.error500_jsp _jspService
SEVERE: javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'site/my_sample_site/contents.css' in servlet with name 'Spring Surf Dispatcher Servlet'
```

In source of that page are div for editor properly defined, also js includes. I tried to define dependencies for resources manualy in my share-config-custom.xml and it looks like it has some effect, because that form div's height  changed, but it's still empty and the same exceptions are logged.

```
<config>
  <forms>
    <dependencies>
      <js src="/modules/editors/ckeditor/ckeditor.js" />
      <js src="/components/editors/ckeditor/ckeditorloader.js" />
      <js src="/modules/editors/ckeditor/lang/cs.js" />
      . . .
      <js src="/modules/editors/ckeditor/skins/kama/editor.css" />
      <js src="/modules/editors/ckeditor/contents.css" />
    </dependencies>
  </forms>
</config>
```

I added all missing things, which appeared while running, but not any more effect.

My question is: why is 'something' still trying to access resources within relative path to site within editor is? I defined resources manualy, so why are they not accepted?

Answer (score 0):

I did propose some change to make it works for 4.2.c, with images attributes and with property edition !

https://github.com/fliot/ckeditor-forms

Hope they will be soon pulled in master branch.

Regards Francois

Comment: I'm sorry, that project is passed away, so I cant try your answer anymore :)

Answer (score 0):

In Alfresco 4.2.2, I achieved it by adding the dependencies in form.js.ftl and form.css.ftl files.

```
<@script type="text/javascript" src="${url.context}/res/components/editors/ckeditor/ckeditorloader.js" group="form"/>
<@script type="text/javascript" src="${url.context}/res/components/editors/ckeditor/config.js" group="form"/>
<@script type="text/javascript" src="${url.context}/res/modules/editors/ckeditor/ckeditor.js" group="form"/>
<@script type="text/javascript" src="${url.context}/res/modules/editors/ckeditor/config.js" group="form"/>
<@script type="text/javascript" src="${url.context}/res/modules/editors/ckeditor/lang/en.js" group="form"/>
<@script type="text/javascript" src="${url.context}/res/modules/editors/ckeditor/plugins/image/dialogs/image.js" group="form"/>
<@script type="text/javascript" src="${url.context}/res/modules/editors/ckeditor/plugins/styles/styles/default.js" group="form"/>



<@link href="${url.context}/res/modules/editors/ckeditor/skins/kama/editor.css" group="form"/>
<@link href="${url.context}/res/modules/editors/ckeditor/skins/kama/dialog.css" group="form"/>
<@link href="${url.context}/res/modules/editors/ckeditor/contents.css" group="form"/>
```